# JavaScript problems in html

Tags: javascript, html, regex

HTML code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Registration</title>
    <script src="val_registration.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
        <form action="" method="post" id="myform">
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td><label for="Last_name">Last name:<span id="imp">*</span></label></td><td><input type="text" id="Last_name" tabindex="5"/>
        <br/><span class="eg">&nbsp;eg:Le You</span></td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><label for="E_mail">E-mail:<span id="imp">*</span></label></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="E_mail" tabindex="10"/>
        <br/><span class="eg">&nbsp;eg:abc123@hotmail.com</span></td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><input type="submit" value="Confirm" id="confirm2" tabindex="11" onclick="val_registration ()"/>
        <input type="reset" value="Cancel" id="cancel2" tabindex="12"/></td>
        </tr>
        </table> 
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript code:

```
    function val_registration () {

    var err = "";    
    var val_Last_name = document.getElementById("Last_name").value;
    var string_Last_name = /^[a-zA-Z@'-_().,]{1,}$/;

    if (val_Last_name == null || val_Last_name == "" || !string_Last_name.test(val_Last_name))    

    {
        err += "\u2022Lastname cannot be blank/Lastname can contain\n alphabets or special symbols(@ ' - _ ( ).,) only.\n";
    }   


    var val_E_mail = document.getElementById("E_mail").value;
    var atpos = val_E_mail.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = val_E_mail.lastIndexOf(".");

    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2> = val_E_mail.length)

    {
        err += "\u2022E-mail cannot be blank/E-mail format must follow\n the example provided.\n";
    }

    alert(err);}
```

Based on the following codes, I would like to ask 3 questions:

First, why didn't the alert pop up??Is there anything wrong with my e-mail validation??

Second, why erroneous data such as <, >, /, * and etc can be entered into the last name field although I have this regular expression (/^[a-zA-Z@'-_().,]{1,}$/)? I just want the users to enter alphabetic data and the special symbols given in the regular expression above.Furthermore, I also found that the combination of both numeric and alphabetic data can be entered to this field also. Why did it happen?

Third, can I remove the border of input field? If this can be done, then how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why didn't the alert pop up??Is there anything wrong with my e-mail validation??

You had `> =`, when it should be `>=`. And use `===` for comparing with `null`.

---

> why erroneous data such as <, >, /, * and etc can be entered

Because part of your regex is `'-_`. The `-` in a character class in the form `x-y` means allow all characters in the range from `x` to `y`, and `<` falls in the range of `'` and `_`.

Solution? Use

```
 `/^[a-zA-Z@'\-_()\.,]{1,}$/`.
         ^-- escaped it
```

---

> can I remove the border of input field? If this can be done, then how to do it?

Use:

```
input[type='text']{ /* only textboxes */
    border:none;   /*No border nor outline*/
    outline:none;  
    -webkit-user-select:none;  /*Disable user-select - the blue border when user clicks 
    TODO:add vendor prefixes for user-select*/
}
```

#### [FULLY FIXED CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/RDrt2/1/)

Answer (score 1):

change the below line

```
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2> = val_E_mail.length)
```

to

```
if (atpos<1 || dotpos< (atpos+2) || (dotpos+2) >= val_E_mail.length)
```

you need to add double quotes.

Comment: After I add double quotes, the erroneous data still can pass.

Comment: @PrabhakarManthena If you add quotes, then `.test` won't work. TypeError. Second, the real problem doesn't pertain to quotes, but with the `-`.

Comment: @user3310635 Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22706040/javascript-problems-in-html/22706571#22706571).

Answer (score 1):

1 You have a syntax error in your code:
`if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2> = val_E_mail.length)`

should become

`if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2 >= val_E_mail.length)`

(notice the >=)

2 take a closer look at your regex and notice this part: `'-_`
It actually sees this as a range. Escape your `-` character: `\-`, or place it at the very end of your character range.

3 `input { border:none; }`

This should answer all of your questions.
However, next time do try to separate these into different questions on SO, as this would normally be closed for not being specific enough.

Answer (score 1):

## 1. to check for blank inputs

instead of writing

```
val_Last_name == null || val_Last_name == ""
```

it is better to use, so that you can eliminate blank spaces in your use case

```
val_Last_name.trim()
```

you don't need to check for null values since you are the one specifying the DOM's ID.

## 2. as for the email validation you can use this

```
function check_email(email) {
    var valid_email = /^\s*[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\@[\w\-\+_]+\.[\w\-\+_]+(\.[\w\-\+_]+)*\s*$/;
    return String(email).search (valid_email) != -1;
}
```

br

## 3. to remove border, you can do this via css

```
input
{
border: 0px;
}
```

additional tip: use jQuery (write less, do more)

your document.getElementById("element") becomes $('#element')

Comment: I haven't learnt them yet so I don't know how to use the functions and also the regular expression.But anyways,I appreciate your answers:)